# How to get country iso code with country name into select

Tags: php, arrays

I am testing a country select, but need 2 values from the array.

1. **country iso code**
2. **country name**

The var `$euData` is now only presenting the country name.

> Q: how do I get country iso code also in the select?

```
function get_europe_multi() {
global $wpdb;
$europe_multi_array = array();
$europe_multi_array = array(
"0"  => __('-- Select Country--', 'agent-plugin'),
"AT" => 'Austria',
"BE" => 'Belgium',
"BG" => 'Bulgaria',
"CY" => 'Cyprus',
"CZ" => 'Czech Republic'
);
return $europe_multi_array ;
}

$content .= '<form id="form" name="country_select_form_test" method="post" action="">';
$content .= '<select class="select-sme-size" name="country_select[]" id="countries_select">';
    foreach(get_europe_multi() as $euData){
        $content .= '<option  value="'.$euData.'">'. $euData .  '</option>';
    }
$content .= '</select><i class="fa fa-check" style="display:none;"></i>';
$content .= '<button type="submit" class="fusion-button button-grey" style="marging-left: 30px;">'. __('test', 'agent-plugin').'</button>';
$content .= '</form>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `foreach` allows you to define a `key` and `value`:

> **foreach**
>
> foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
>
> http://php.net/foreach

So you just need to update your `foreach` code block slightly. Based on your data example the country code is the `$key` and the country name is the `$value`.

Assuming you want the key as the select value you can use something like this:

```
foreach(get_europe_multi() as $key => $value) {
     $content .= '<option  value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

However, this will allow you to do anything you want with the `$key` and `$value` inside your loop.

Here is a working demo: https://eval.in/871252